# Is there a software utility available that allows simultaneous reading of Spanish and English material?

Tags: traducción

I would like to have an app (that runs on the desktop, not a phone app - text would be too small) that would allow me to simultaneously have both the Spanish and the English versions of material displayed side-by-side.

Specifically, I want to read Don Quixote that way; but actually, I would like to be able to load any pair of documents in that way. IOW, it'd be nice to be able to download the Spanish html and the English html (or text files) and load them up in this utility.

The optimum would be if scrolling down in one of the panes simultaneously caused the other pane to scroll down with it, but would also allow independent scrolling for those cases where one or the other panes passages was longer.

IOW, I guess a "global" scrolling action to scroll them together as well as an independent scrolling action for each of the two panes. Is there such a utility available?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask it on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software, not about Spanish language and its usage. 

Comment: Write a comment if you want this question to be migrated to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Sure, that would be fine to migrate it, if you think that's a better spot for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is having two browser windows side by side with the same Spanish document in both, and then using Google translate on one of them.  They won't scroll together because only one window at a time can request from the OS to have "focus".

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, too, but if I went that route I would have the Spanish in one, and an English in the other; Don Quixote, for example, is available in the original (Spanish) and in English from project Gutenberg. I'm sure many other works are, too.

Comment: I've done this a ton of times, and I agree it'd be nice to have a utility like this - but I haven't found one either.  I became deft with Alt-Tab and PageDown.  It does a good enough job.  To note, many Biblical translation sites have two translations side-by-side, so the potential is there.